# Embedded mongo (flapdoodle) does not start in Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-database, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to upgrade from Spring Boot `1.4` to `1.5.2`. As far as I can tell I've followed the update guidelines.

There are actually two issues, the main one which is to do with embedded mongo:

**EmbeddedServletContainerFactory now has to be explicitly created**

In the test config class I've had to add this:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setSessionTimeout(50, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    return factory;
}
```

I did not have to do this before. I had to include it because when I run a test it gives me this error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.`

**Embedded Mongo will not start**

Now I get this error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'embeddedMongoServer' available`

No idea where I should be adding this bean (and indeed why I should be adding it)

**My current setup**

I have multiple tests that extend `BaseIT`, which starts like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfig.class, TestMongoConfig.class},, webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, value = "
{$server.port}")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class BaseIT {...}
```

Mongo config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "...")
public class TestMongoConfig {
@Bean public MongoClient mongo(){...}
@Bean public MongodProcess mongodProcess(){...}
@Bean public MongodExecutable mongodExecutable(){...}
@Bean public IMongodConfig mongodConfig(){...}
@Bean public MongodStarter mongodStarter(){...}
}
```

Test config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(value = {...})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {...)
@EnableWebMvc
public class TestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

Comment: Why have you written your own configuration for embedded Mongo rather than using the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot?

Comment: The missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory is probably because you're trying to use both `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataMongoTest` at the same time. Doing so doesn't really make sense as they're two different types of test: a full-blown integration test and a test focussed on data access using Spring Data MongoDB respectively

Comment: @AndyWilkinson the test config for mongo was there as a hangover from boot 1.3 - I didn't realise it wasn't needed in 1.4+

Comment: @AndyWilkinson and excluding the mongo config and adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to `BaseIT` causes a different error, `No auto-configuration attributes found. Is MyTest annotated with EnableAutoConfiguration?`

Comment: You don't need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on `BaseIT` if you're using `@SpringBootTest` or `@DataMongoTest`. As things stand you're over complicating things and asking two or three questions at the same time. I'd recommend taking a step back and producing a minimal example of your problem. In doing so, I suspect you'll find the answers.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson there's only 1 question, really, which is what I need to do to get embedded to work as it was in `1.4.5`. `@SpringBootTest` makes sense to me. But not including `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or excluding `TestMongoConfig.class` results in `Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials must be specified`, which insinuates the config class is needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141420/discussion-between-user2393012-and-andy-wilkinson).